# ConnectException thrown using ServerSocket

Tags: java

The following code is correct when compiled, but when run it says: ConnectException
the error image:

[image: error image]

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class TcpChat 
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
Socket s = new Socket("Ip",20000);
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(20000);

new Thread(new TcpClient(s)).start();
new Thread(new TcpServer(ss)).start();
 }
 }

class TcpClient implements Runnable
 {
Socket s;
TcpClient(Socket s)
 {
this.s = s;
 }

public void run()
 {
try
 {
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
out.write("hello javaserver".getBytes());
s.close();
 }
catch (Exception e)
{
 }
 }
 }

class TcpServer implements Runnable
{
ServerSocket ss;
TcpServer(ServerSocket ss)
 {
this.ss = ss;
 }

public void run()
 {
try
{
Socket s = ss.accept();
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
byte[] buf =new byte[1024];
int length =in.read(buf);
String ip =s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
String data = new String(buf,0,length);

System.out.println(ip+":::"+data);

s.close();
ss.close();


 }
catch (Exception e)
{
}
}



}
```

---

Additionally, there is no error about the IP address I use, in my PC I use my own IP.

Comment: Hint: you can copy-and-paste the exception from the Command Line Window if you hold down shift while marking it.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer thank you so much for teach me.I really don't notice it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your whole code, so it's hard to check, but it seems like you try to connect to a port (i.e. open the client socket) *before* you actually open the server socket. That won't work, of course, since there's nothing listening at that port yet (thus: connection refused).

Answer (score 1):

Change your main method like

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(20000);
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 20000);
    new Thread(new TcpServer(ss)).start();
    new Thread(new TcpClient(s)).start();
```

You can find a better example for `Chat Server` [here](http://inetjava.sourceforge.net/lectures/part1_sockets/InetJava-1.9-Chat-Client-Server-Example.html). Also you can read about `sockets` from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

Comment: no ,it's not the question you say ,as my addition says,in my PC，I have set the IP adress in Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 20000);but thanks for your answer as well.

Comment: Problem is you have to start server socket before client socket so it will work this way.